# Nexus 5 signal drops immediately when making call

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, calls, nexus-5, network-signal, nexus

My Nexus 5 running on Marshmallow and it has Last ota security update provided by Google at the time of end of support.

I’ve a perfectly working SIM card. Using this sim card to make calls from nexus 5, but before the call gets placed the mobile signal drops to zero.

When the call is disconnected the signal resumes back to normal.

I tried soft reset, hard reset and airplane mode on/off. But nothing works.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: No signal at all or no data signal? Meaning are you able to actually make the phone call but the internet doesn't work, or is it that the call hangs up as soon as you try calling?

Comment: The second case. Network signal drops off and call hangs up the moment I place the call.

Comment: In that case i would suggest trying the sim card in another phone, that way you can find out if the problem is with the phone or sim card.

Comment: As I mentioned the SIM card works perfectly in other mobiles and able to make calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently I have installed `Lineage OS Android 8.1.0 (Oreo)` custom ROM in Nexus 5.

It has resolved the issue and I'm able to make calls successfully now.

I believe there should be some issue in `Android Connectivity Services` application and it might have got resolved by the OS upgrade.